# user icon to open browser for uploading image

Tags: jquery

I have file icon inside form. when user click on it I would that brower will open and allows him to choose file. how can i make the icon to open the browser?

```
<img class="uploadFileImg" alt="" src="images/photoIconOn.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `input type=file`'s opacity to `0` and write an `click event` to your `img` as below:

```
<img src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg" class="uploadFileImg"/>

<input type="file" style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:30px;opacity:0;" id="selector"/>
```

Click event in `jquery`:

```
$(".uploadFileImg").on('click',function(){
   //on click of image trigger click of input type=file
   $("#selector").trigger('click'); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/VH9yt/126/)**